# Using Microsoft Bot Framework, when I write on Messenger channel, how to push the result to a specific Slack channel ? (with Node)

Tags: node.js, botframework

Currently my users are using a Messenger channel.

Here is what it goes: my users type "Talk to a coach" in my bot, then they can write whatever they want, and then the result should be pushed to a specific private channel using Slack.

How can I achieve that ?

EDIT: The private channel is a list of users request that can be processed when coaches are available, so users don't have to be in a waiting list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved it using directly Slack API. I tried with `.sourceEvent`, and it nearly worked: the bot only talked to me in private on Slack, he didn't accept any channel ID / name (private or not).

Here is how I made it to work (a bit factorized):
It starts with the user wanting to change anything in his planning (which has to be done manually by a coach), so it starts in dialog `"/select_modify_planning"`

app.js:

```
...

bot.dialog("/select_modify_planning", require("./dialogs/modifyPlanning").select);
bot.dialog("/ask_for_request", require("./dialogs/modifyPlanning).askForRequest);

...
```

modifyPlanning.js:

```
const builder = require('botbuilder');
const rp = require('request-promise');

...

exports.select = [
 (session, args) => {
   session.sendTyping();
   builder.Prompts.choice(session, "What do you want to declare ? :)", "Internal hours|Update rendezvous");
 },
 (session, results) => {
  if (results.response) {
    switch (results.response.entity) {
      case "Internal hours":
        session.beginDialog("/ask_for_request");
        break;
      case "Update rendezvous":
        ...
    }
  }
]

...

exports.askForRequest = [
 (session, args) => {
   session.sendTyping();
   builder.Prompts.text(session, "Type your demand please:");
 },
 async (session, results) => {
   try {
     if (results.response)
       await sendRequestToSlack(results.response);
       session.endDialog("Your demand has been sent successfully, thank you ;)");
   }
   .catch(err) {
     console.error(err);
     session.endDialog("There was a problem while sending your demand to a coach, sorry :(");
   }
 }
]

...

const sendRequestToSlack = (textToSend) => {
  var options = {
    uri: "https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage",
    form: {
      "token": "xoxb-XXXXXX-XXXXXX", // Your bot slack token
      "channel": "XXXXXXXXX", // Your channel id (or name)
      "text": textToSend
    },
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
  }
  return rp.post(options);
}

...
```

And here it is.

If you want to know your channels ID (using name is a bad practice because they can be changed), you can use this method: https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.list for public channels, or this one: https://api.slack.com/methods/groups.list for private channels.

If it's for private channels, you have to add good permissions in your bot scope settings ( `groups.xxx` ), and reinstall it (you have a green button dedicated to in bots settings)

Hope everything is clear :)

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the ability to "hand off" a customer from a bot to a human agent.

This topic is depicted in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/bot-design-pattern-handoff-human?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365) and there are several samples available, for Node.js you may be interested in this one: https://github.com/palindromed/Bot-HandOff

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I read official doc and the github handOff, and I don't think it's exactly what I need: I don't want the user to be in a waiting state, I just want the bot to push to a private slack channel the information the user gave, so coaches can process it later (typical information is "I need to be replaced day X at hour Y, thanks bot !")

Comment: Then why don't you use Slack's API?

Comment: I'd like to, but I don't understand how to make the bot framework to specifically use the Slack's API. If I could I'd follow this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-channeldata , but it's in C#, and I'm not sure about how to use it with Node...

Comment: When I'm saying Slack's API, it's not Slack Channel Data in bot framework but directly this one: https://api.slack.com/
You can also use the bot functionalities to start a new conversation (private channel) between the bot and the coach
What would you prefer?

Comment: Yes I already went on api.slack.com, the exact problem is that I don't know how to use this API from the bot. I know it's possible through channelData specific.
And what I want is the bot to post things (like user's request users wrote from Messenger) in a specific channel in Slack: 1) Users write to bot, 2) Bot handle it and write to a Slack's channel

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do and I think you are messing a bit things about the API. The ChannelData object is helpful to do things specific for each channel yes, but it is not handling everything: here it's not useful for you.
2 options: you use Slack API (it's direct HTTP calls: POST, GET...), or you use a new Conversation with the bot (for that you need to know the bot Slack's username and coach Slack's username or email). For this latest option I got working sample code, but in C# sorry

Comment: Ok I see, so just to describe a bit more, the channel in Slack will be named "requests", so there will be all requests in text, from users from messenger channel. A bit like a historic of requests. It is not direct talking.
For that, as you say, there is no possibility from the bot framework to talk in a specific channel, so I have to use [link](api.slack.com), because channelData doesn't handle that (how do I know what it handles ?).
Am I right ?
Anyway, thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146045/discussion-between-nicolas-r-and-pierre-hofman).